# How to change text according to radio button selection using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a dropdown list which contains a set of names.. When select one name, a set of data will be generated from database..

And those data will bind into Radiobutton list control which in placed under the control..

I've a text control with predefined text as "hello"..

Now, that "hello" has to changed with the text I'm selecting in Radiobutton list..

For example, I've "Apple, Orange, Grape" in radio button list.. When I select Apple first time, "Hello" changed to "Apple".. I done this.. But when I select "Orange", "Assple" is not changing.. How to do that..?

```
function SelectChanged(Radiolst)
{
    var mailBdy = document.getElementById("<%=txtEditor.ClientID  %>");
    var toMember = document.getElementById(Radiolst);
    var selectedTxt=$(toMember).find(":checked").next().html();
    var newBod = $(mailBdy).val();
    newBod=newBod.replace('Hello',selectedTxt);
    mailBdy.value = newBod;
    alert(mailBdy.value);
}
```

The function `SelectChanged` is Client function of Radiobutton list.. First time alert shows "Apple" , but next time its not changes..

Here is the txtEditor and Radiobutton list control ASP.NET coding..

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="lstTo" runat="server"   ></asp:RadioButtonList>

<textarea id="txtEditor" name="txtEditor" style="width: 100% ; height :300px " runat="server" enableviewstate ="true"  > </textarea>
```

Comment: Because in first change, your code searches 'Hello' and changes it. In second change, your code still searches for 'Hello' and can't find it. You have to post your HTML code.

Comment: Post your html for clarification

Comment: HTML code of what, Radio button list or txteditor?

Comment: Anything that concerns the current problem.

Comment: In your string newbod you are searching for hello and replacing it with your selection.  You should just do an assignment: $(mailbdy).val(selectedtext). Also this spaghetti of vanilla JavaScript and jquery i would not recommend it.

Comment: is this http://jsfiddle.net/pawnx59p/2/ what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Since the markup hasn't been provided I'm taking a guess here:

For HTML like:

```
<select>
<option value="orange">
<option value="apple">
</select>
<input type="radio" id="Radiolst" value="Hello" name="some">
```

jQuery should be like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('select').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    $("#Radiolst").val(valueSelected);
    $("#txtEditor").text(valueSelected);
  });
});
```

Do remember to put this in the `<head>` tag of the document.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5y43jy4e/5/)

Comment: Ok.. Thanks..
If I've two texts "Hello Fruit" and I wanna change the "Fruit" alone with the radio list select means, how to do that?

Comment: Yes, it is.. But for me, the txtEditor is not replacing.. But in alert, it changes..

Comment: May be you have more than one <textarea> with same id

Comment: I've only one.. Even as u says, how it changes Fruit to Apple and shows alert correctly..?

Comment: I didn't told `txtEditor` changes.. I told and shows `alert` correctly.. Look again.. I'm in need of help.. So if I post contradicting statements, you guys can't help me correctly..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var globalVar = 'hello';
function SelectChanged(Radiolst)
{
    var mailBdy = document.getElementById("<%=txtEditor.ClientID  %>");
    var toMember = document.getElementById(Radiolst);
    var selectedTxt=$(toMember).find(":checked").next().html();
    var newBod = $(mailBdy).val();
    newBod=newBod.replace(globalVar,selectedTxt);
    globalVar = selectedTxt;
    mailBdy.value = newBod;
    alert(mailBdy.value);
}
```